# Cannot import Container from NextUi

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, frontend, tailwind-css

Hey guys I am pretty new at nodejs and I am having an issue when I try to use some components from `NextUI`. Basically, I followed the installation steps from [here](https://v2.nextui.org/docs/guide/installation) but it says
`Module'@nextui-org/react' has no exported member Container` for both components below:

`import { Container, useToasts } from '@nextui-org/react';`

Neverthless, these 2 imports are working fine for same library,

`import {  Input, Button } from '@nextui-org/react';`

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.15",
    "next": "^14.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.6",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}
```

And I am using node 18.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Container might be deprecated at NextUi version 2

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` you have the following dependency:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@nextui-org/react": "^2.2.9",
  ....
}
```

In NextUI ^2.0.0 the `Container` layout component, does not exist (you can find the available components for ^2.0.0 versions in [the official docs](https://nextui.org/docs/components/navbar)).

If you really want to use the `Container` component, you need to use NextUI ^1.0.0. On this version, you should be able to use [containers](https://v1.nextui.org/docs/layout/container).

---

My suggestion would be to either:

- Rebase your project to NextUI ^1.0.0, to be able to use containers.
- Or, use the components you have available in ^2.0.0